# Acquire Windows gui on linux

Tags: linux, windows, wine

I wish to work completely on Linux. However, some tools which I must use only have the Windows version. For example, some communication tools which must be consistent with others only have the Windows version. There are some solutions for this situation.

1. Run `exe` files on Linux, e.g., wine.
2. Use Windows virtual machine.

I tried `wine`, however, it failes to use the camera which may be necessary. About virtual machine, when I need to share some thing on the linux desktop or terminal though windows apps, I think the apps can not reach them.

Many thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to work completely on Linux. However, some tools which I must
> use only have the Windows version.

I have been doing this for quite a long time. There are several virtualizing apps - I like VMware Professional the best because it is easy to use and flexible. Comes in Windows and Linux flavors.

The Host machine should be made for working with VMs.  I use a machine with an i7 CPU, fast NVMe SSD drive, and 16 GB of memory for Host and 2 or 3 active machines. Works great.

Choose your Host OS as the OS you use the most, and use VMs for lesser used operating systems.

> About virtual machine, when I need to share some thing on the linux
> desktop or terminal though windows apps,

I do this routinely.

From Linux to Windows:  SMB//hostmachine/sharedfolder.

From Windows to Linux:  Install Samba on Linux.  \192.168.x.y where this is the IP of the Linux Machine

All the above works fine and over 95% of the time, trouble free.